Connecting to MySQL: Didn't find class "javax.security.sasl.SaslClientFactory"
I'm using a real device. I purchased database MySQL on a cloud server. I made a connection to it. When trying to log into the database through phpMyAdmin, everything works correctly but when i try to log in through the application code, exceptions are thrown, I added them below. I also added the code for connecting to the database and part of the code from gradle and manifest for a better understanding. I would like to get at least some advice for the direction in which to move to solve the problem
code:
private fun changeScrollView() {
        val thread = object : Thread(){
            override fun run(){
                try {
                    Log.d("Thread", "Start loading")
                    events = mySqlHelper.getEventsByDate(roomId, chosenDate).sortedBy { it.time }
                    Log.d("Thread", "First loaded successfully")
                    tasks = mySqlHelper.getTasksByDate(chosenDate, roomId).sortedBy { it.time }
                    Log.d("Thread", "Loaded successfully")

                    val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
                    handler.postDelayed({
                        createAllEventsAndTasks()
                    }, 0)
                }catch (e: Exception){
                    Log.e("Thread","Error: ${e.message}", e)
                }
            }
        }

        thread.start()
    }

mysqlhelper:
private val url = "jdbc:mysql://mysql.hosting.nic.ru:3306/h406497953_db"
    private val username = "h406497953_mysql"
    private val passwordUrl = "************************"

    private fun getConnection(): Connection {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, passwordUrl)
    }


fun getEventsByDate(roomId: Int, date :String) :List<Event>{
        val connection = getConnection()
        val query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE idRoom =? AND data =?"
        val preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query)
        preparedStatement.setInt(1,roomId)
        preparedStatement.setDate(2,java.sql.Date.valueOf(date))
        val resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()
        val events = mutableListOf<Event>()
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            val event = Event(
                data = resultSet.getDate("data").toString(),
                time = resultSet.getString("time"),
                place = resultSet.getString("place"),
                event = resultSet.getString("event")
            )
            events.add(event)
        }
        connection.close()
        return events
    }

gradle
implementation (libs.mysql.connector.java.v8022)

manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

exceptions
Start loading
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
Process: com.example.helper1, PID: 15374
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/security/sasl/SaslClientFactory;
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.authentication.AuthenticationLdapSaslClientPlugin.<clinit>(AuthenticationLdapSaslClientPlugin.java:59)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.loadAuthenticationPlugins(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:387)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1348)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:157)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826) 
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.security.sasl.SaslClientFactory" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.helper1/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.helper1/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes5.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~8xorLfwXJG9tw6gBIhW1aQ==/com.example.helper1-RzqhcYGm2Ltb7G8Bt70gpA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~8xorLfwXJG9tw6gBIhW1aQ==/com.example.helper1-RzqhcYGm2Ltb7G8Bt70gpA==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
... 16 more


Please reconsider your use of JDBC on Android.

I want to use jdbc in order to understand a little how to work with the driver. or are all companies and developers currently using a restful API or web service to connect to the database?

Few mobile apps directly connect to a remote database, for the security and reliability reasons outlined in the linked-to question and answers. JDBC was designed before WiFi was a thing, let alone mobile data.

I encountered similar issue. When trying to connect to postgres through my application it threw a similar exception.I added the below dependency in my application code and it started working.
implementation("com.ongres.scram:client:2.1"). Try using this. It might help.
